# Cannot ping (or otherwise connect to) specific .local domain from Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, zeroconf

I cannot ping my raspberry pi3 (mypi.local) from Windows or WSL, however I *can* ping my NAS (freenas.local) or laptop (Shuttle.local) just fine.

Pinging the Pi works fine from my Linux laptop, it is just the Windows machine that has issues. Every system can ping every other system with the sole exception of the Windows machine pinging the Pi (the other way around works fine).

Using the IP address of the Pi works, but since everything is on DHCP I would really rather not hard-code any addresses into configuration files and such.

Error message:

```
Ping request could not find host mypi.local. Please check the name and try again.
```

The Pi is using Avahi, and Windows is using whatever Windows 10 uses for .local name resolution. The laptop and NAS are both using Avahi as well.

Comment: You may wish to edit the question to include more details regarding the method you are using for name resolution (since this appears to be what's likely failing).

Comment: Alright. I highly doubt it will be helpful, as there are really only three common zeroconf services, only one of which is common on *nix systems and only one common on Windows 10.

Comment: By "only one common on Windows" you're referring to mDNSResponder, *right*? Although Windows 10 is slowly adding mDNS support, I don't believe it's currently capable of native mDNS `.local` name resolution _at all_, and in all my tests it merely does LLMNR lookups for those instead.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but this [raspberrypi.se question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45198/cant-connect-to-pi-on-local-network-via-hostname-local-on-windows) indicates that the current version of [Bonjour](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999?locale=en_US) seems to be more reliable for zeroconf .local setups with the Pi.

Comment: That did the trick. Seems Windows was just being flaky, and a better resolver/driver/whatever was all that was needed. Odd that pinging the laptop and the NAS (which also use Avahi) works fine, but not pinging the Pi...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems the the Windows implementation of zeroconf is poor, at least in relation to the Pi. According to this [raspberrypi.se question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45198/cant-connect-to-pi-on-local-network-via-hostname-local-on-windows), Apple's current version of [Bonjour](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999?locale=en_US) is preferable on Windows.